# RavenDB 5.4 serializing and deserializing Decimal format

Tags: json.net, deserialization, ravendb

I have a requirement that decimal values retrieved from RavenDB have the **exact** same format they were stored as.

Example property value 33

The serialized json stored in DB have the value stored exactly as 33, which is as expected. But when deserializing I get value 33.0 in the Decimal property.

I have tried with a custom JsonConverter just to inspect what happens when deserializing

```
public class DecimalFormatConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(decimal);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(reader.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue((decimal)value);
    }
}
```

In ReadJson, when inspecting **reader.Value** it is 33.0 (should be 33). I cannot implement a rounding or custom formatting here, since if the value was stored as 33.0 or 33.00 it MUST keep the exact same format when loaded.

I have set

```
serializer.FloatParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.FloatParseHandling.Decimal;
```

although this is probably not relevant in this case.

Comment: " I get value 33.0 in the Decimal property"  Where did you get it? in visual studio debugger? You question is not correct. The value  can be shown any way you want, but the value is always the same inside of  a variable. You have to show the whole code including a model,  not just  a converter that you don' t need at all

Comment: @Serge: No, the value is NOT the same. Read the Explanation paragraph in the first post here: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1726. Decimal 33 and Decimal 33.0 is represented differently in memory, although they will compare as equal. I inspect the value in VS debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning! The solution posted by @Ayende Rahien with the second comment, has a serious potential bug.

If the code is run with different Cultures decimal formats (f.ex decimal separator . or , depending on Culture) it will mess up the decimals.

The best solution I have found so far is:

```
public class DecimalFormatConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(decimal) || objectType == typeof(decimal?);
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null)
            return null;

        return Convert.ToDecimal(reader.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
        
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

At the JSON level, numbers are doubles, not decimals.
The problem is at the serialization level: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1726

That has several implications, but basically means that you need to write the data to the output format using the proper format.

You need to use `FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal` and the following converter:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString());
}
```

Note that we write the value of the decimal *as a string* to the output, without using quotes.
When parsing, `FloatParseHandling.Decimal` will read it as decimal and the rest is fine.

Note that server side operations, however, will use doubles internally.

See also:

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/server/kb/numbers-in-ravendb
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/client-api/configuration/serialization#numbers-deserialization

Comment: Trying the writer.WriteRawValue method gives Exception:

System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=Specified method is not supported.
  Source=Raven.Client
  StackTrace:
   at Raven.Client.Json.Serialization.NewtonsoftJson.Internal.BlittableJsonWriter.WriteRawValue(String json)

Comment: In that case, use `WriteValue` directly on the string. The value would be a string server side, of course, but that is the easiest way to ensure the roundtripping

Answer (score 0):

The reader.Value property returns a string representation of the decimal value, which includes the trailing ".0" for whole numbers. Modify your ReadJson method to parse the string representation of the decimal value instead of using the Convert.ToDecimal method.

```
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
    {
        string value = (string)reader.Value;
        if (decimal.TryParse(value, out decimal result))
            return result;
    }
    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Float)
    {
        // Preserve the exact format
        return decimal.Parse(reader.Value.ToString(), 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work, reader.Value already have a value of 33.0 when entering the ReadJson method and as I mentioned I have a requirement to return the value exactly in the format it was stored.
By the way, I can confirm that the TokenType is JsonToken.Float